# Why this simple example of pyqtgraph is not working?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqtgraph

The following code is just for testing the speed of the pyqtgraph. What I was expected is to get alternating graph forever. However, nothing is shown in the widget after executing this code. What is the problem?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from random import randint, uniform
from math import *
import pyqtgraph as pg
import time

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x=pg.PlotWidget(self)
        self.x.setMinimumHeight(400)
        self.x.setMinimumWidth(400)
        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
        self.u=[i+uniform(1,30) for i in range(1000)]
        self.v=[-i+uniform(1,30) for i in range(1000)]
        self.show()

    def Run(self):
        while 1:
            self.x.clear()
            self.x.plot(self.u)
            self.x.clear()
            self.x.plot(self.v)

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
ex=Example()
ex.Run()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally a bad idea to use a while loop in a GUI. The problem is that it's preventing the GUI to remain responsive and handle all GUI events.

An option is to use a timer instead, e.g. a simple `QTimer`. In order to switch between the two different datasets to plot you would also introduce some mechanism as to which one should be shown.

```
import sys
#from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
#from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from random import randint, uniform
import pyqtgraph as pg

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.x=pg.PlotWidget(self)
        self.x.setMinimumHeight(400)
        self.x.setMinimumWidth(400)
        self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized)
        self.u=[i+uniform(1,30) for i in range(1000)]
        self.v=[-i+uniform(1,30) for i in range(1000)]
        self.switch = True
        self.show()

    def start(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.run)
        self.timer.start(500)

    def run(self):
        if self.switch:
            self.x.clear()
            self.x.plot(self.u)
        else:
            self.x.clear()
            self.x.plot(self.v)
        self.switch = not self.switch

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex=Example()
ex.start()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```